# Postman gives a success response while the same API throws error when called through code

Tags: ios, objective-c, postman, nsurlconnection

[image]

A POST API throws error when I call it in my code while gives a success response through postman. I use the same method to call other services and they work just fine. The problem is with this particular API. Here is the code I use for calling the API:

```
-(void)createNSUrlSessionLogin:(NSURL*)URL postDict:(NSDictionary*)dict successBlock:(completionBlock)completionBlock
              failureBlock:(failureBlock)failure
{
NSError *error;
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
    {            
        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"result json: %@", jsonArray);
        if (!jsonArray) {
            failure(NO,nil);
        }else
        {
            completionBlock(YES,jsonArray);
        }

    }

    else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
        failure(NO,nil);
    }

    else if (error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Error is %@",[error description]);
        failure(NO,nil);
    }

}];

[postDataTask resume];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If Gennady's answer doesn't work you could use a proxy (like Charles) to check for other differences

Comment: @Simon thanks, I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, i'm cannot write comments. But I see, that you do content-type: url-encoded request via postman, and application-json via code. If API accept only url-encoded requests, this is your answer.

Comment: Zyablistsev thanks man. How could I miss that. I will have to talk to the back end people. They developed the other APIs with content type as application-json only. Thats why I didnt bother to notice it.

Comment: Note that you can ask PostMan to generate Objective-C. It's not beautiful code, but it could help you point out the difference (headers, how the body is encoded, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

-(void)serverRequestFetchData:(NSMutableURLRequest*)request withCallback:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))aCallback {

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSHTTPURLResponse *statusResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
        if (statusResponse.statusCode >= 200 && statusResponse.statusCode < 300) {
            if (data.length > 0 && error == nil) {
                NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
                if (aCallback) {
                    aCallback(array, nil);
                }
            } else {
                aCallback(@[], error);
            }
        } else {
            NSString *statusMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invalid status response code: %ld", (unsigned long)statusResponse.statusCode];
            NSError *statusError = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"com.somedomain" code:10001 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : NSLocalizedString(statusMessage, nil)}];
            if (aCallback) {
                aCallback(@[], statusError);
            }
        }
    });
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

}

-(void)myRequest {

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"access_token\":\"ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE\"}"];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR_FIRST_URL_STRING"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];

[self serverRequestFetchData:request withCallback:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error) {
}];
```

}